# Get Outlook RSS Feed notifications on first create rather than every updates

Tags: outlook, rss, rss-reader, sitefinity-5

We have an Outlook RSS rule and get notification on every updates of the related news. However, we would like to get only the notification on first creation of the news instead of every updates of the related news. Is it possible in Outlook RSS?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Items.ItemAdd/ItemChange events on a particular folder's Items collection? You can use MAPIFolder.Folders.FolderAdd eventon the root RSS folder.

Comment: The notifications are published on our web site and its CMS uses Sitefinity. As far as I see there is no config in Outlook if the related content is added or updated. Any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do - when Outlook performs Send/Receive, it processes RSS feeds and downloads new posts. What exactly are you trying to do from the end user point of view in Outlook?

Comment: Dear Dimitry, we want to get Outlook RSS notification ONLY when a content page is first added. On the other hand, we do not want to get notification mail when the same content page's every update. For now we get notifications for both adding and updating of the same content. If it is not clear please let me clarify you a little bit more. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think I can do that unless you somehow tweak the RSS software that generates the feed.